# Google Maps Info window's resizing based on the internal content

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, autolayout

I'm creating custom Info Window using this method `- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker` based on the `UIStoryboard` using Autolayout. I expect that some of the internal views will be resized due to the actual text information will be received and the final size of the Info Window will be different from the view of IB.

Actually, as the result my InfoWindow view tries to be full screen sized, and nothing helps to fix this. Playing with `autoresizingMask` doesn't change anything, the same result with setting `Hugging Priority`. The only way is to set a fixed size constraint, I've done this for width. But for height I need dynamically calculated size based on the real size of the internal content.

**UPDATE:** Added screenshots from Storyboard

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: Sample test with 2 scroll views, with overridden method `intrinsicContentSize`:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    return self.contentSize;
}
```

Internal UIScrollView attached via all 4 sides to base scrollview
[image: Internal UIScrollView attached via all 4 sides to base scrollview]

internal UIScrollView attached to the top and left only
[image: internal UIScrollView attached to the top and left only]
Sample test view hierarchy
[image: Sample test view hierarchy]

As you can see full screen root `UIScrollView` (blue border) still exists. And internal `UIScrollView` (green color) has no influence on it. It's still has full screen size

Comment: Can you post your code / storyboard screenshot?

Comment: For height, you need to set the `vertical spacing` (both top and bottom) between your labels and the `UIView`. if you have too many labels in your `UIView`, you should consider use `UIScrollView` instead.

Comment: ztan, good idea, unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. See UPDATE 2

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the only way I found is to use explicit frame, which needs to be calculated manually and **do not use Autolayout at all with Google Maps InfoWindow**.

I made a couple of tests to verify how the same view displayed as the subview of `UIWindow`, and found that the behavior is different.

Comment: Interesting discovery. I suspect this may be a source of troubles I'm facing with a custom UIView for the marker itself. For now I'll be following your advice and sizing manually.